# NHibernate Interceptor to modify transaction level

Tags: nhibernate, interceptor, system.data.sqlite, isolation-level

Trying to use SQLite for unit testing which is working fine, testing some of the repositories however is probomatic because they use transactions.

For the transactions that use ReadCommitted everything is fine, however some of them use ReadUncommitted which having a look at System.Data.SQLite does not support:

```
if ((this._defaultIsolation != IsolationLevel.Serializable) && (this._defaultIsolation != IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
        throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid Default IsolationLevel specified");
}
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to intercept the Session.BeginTransaction(...) so i can change the transaction level, only for unit tests.

**Update:**
My solution was to download the sourcecode for System.Data.SQLite and modify the exceptions to set the default isolation level. I Bloggled about it here:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/01/system-data-sqlite-isolationlevel-exception/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't easy extensibility points for that, short of implementing `ITransactionFactory` and `ITransaction`.

It's probably easier to wrap the call to `BeginTransaction` to avoid using ReadUncommitted when testing.

Comment: Yeah thats what I wanted to avoid doing since this is only affecting unit testing and not the application. What I ended up doing last night was downloading the source code for System.Data.SQLite and modifying the two checks it does for isolationlevel, and changing it to serializable instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: My solution: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/01/system-data-sqlite-isolationlevel-exception/